# How to change cv :: Mat value according to tolerance

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am new in C++, until now I was programming in Python.

I have a cv :: Mat and I want to pass all pixels greater than 100 to 255, if they are less than 100 I pass them to 0.

In python it would be:

```py
imgDst(imgDst > 100) = 255.
imgDst(imgDst <= 100) = 0.
```

Can anyone tell me what this operation would look like in C ++? Obviously without going through the matrix pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use a member method of `cv::Mat`:

```
imgDst.setTo(255, imgDst > 100);
```

and similary

```
imgDst.setTo(0, imgDst <= 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LUT](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=lut#lut)

```
std::vector<char> lut(256);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    lut[i] = i > 100 ? 255 : 0;
}

cv::LUT(imgDst, lut, imgDst);
```

Comment: Using a LUT is not the most elegant way to do this operation.  There are more vectorized ways to do what the OP is asking, such as those seen in the other answers.

Comment: Agree, just proposed one way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a binary operation on the image where anything that statisfies the expression will convert the image to a CV_8UC1 with 255 satisfying the operation and 0 otherwise.  In your case, the binary operation is the greater than or equal operation:

```
cv::Mat imgDst;
// ...
// Do operations here...
//
imgDst = imgDst > 100;
```

There's no need to use a lookup table at all.